# Concourse reusing the job remplates effectively

Tags: concourse

I have the following piece of code

```
job-template: &job-template
plan:
- get: project-x.git
trigger: true
- task: t1
config:
platform: linux
image_resource:
type: docker-image
source: {repository: alpine}
run:
path: echo
args: [“Hello, world!”]

###############################################################################

resources:

name: project-x.git
type: git
source:
uri: https://github.com/marco-m/concourse-pipelines.git
branch: master
###############################################################################

jobs:

name: j1
<<: *job-template
name: j2
<<: *job-template
name: j3
<<: *job-template
name: j4
<<: *job-template
name: j5
<<: *job-template
```

Instead of all the jobs printing “Hello, World!” , i want to pass a string variable from the Job to Job template , so that each job prints differently.
“Hello, World! am from j1”
“Hello, World! am from j2”

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [params](https://concourse-ci.org/jobs.html#schema.step.task-step.params) stanza, that will make available the key/value pairs as environmental variables to the task. Something along the lines of:

```yaml
config-template: &config-template
  config:
    platform: linux
    image_resource:
      type: registry-image
      source: {repository: alpine}
    params:
      NAME: world
    run:
      path: sh
      args:
        - -ce
        - echo "Hello, $NAME!"

jobs:
- name: j1
  plan:
  - task: t1
    params:
      NAME: A
    <<: *config-template
- name: j2
  plan:
  - task: t2
    params:
      NAME: B
    <<: *config-template
- name: j3
  plan:
  - task: t3
    params:
      NAME: C
    <<: *config-template
```

But instead, I would use a separate [task file](https://concourse-ci.org/tasks.html).

As an aside, since you are using one of the examples from [marco-m/concourse-pipelines](https://github.com/marco-m/concourse-pipelines), I suggest to check out another project of mine, [marco-m/concourse-in-a-box](https://github.com/marco-m/concourse-in-a-box): an all-in-one Concourse CI/CD system based on Docker Compose, with Minio S3-compatible storage and HashiCorp Vault secret manager. This enables to learn Concourse pipelines from scratch in a simple and complete environment.